# GCP terraform compute instance template labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a TF GCP `google_compute_instance_template` configured to deploy a range of individual VMs, each of which will perform a different role in a "micro-services" style application. I am adding a single label to my instance_template, `costing="app"`. However when I go to deploy the various VM components of the app with `google_compute_instance_group_manager`, I was expecting to be able to add another label in the in the instance group manager configuration, specific to the VM that is being deployed, such as "component=blah".  The google_compute_instance_group_manager is not talking `labels` as a configuration element. Does anyone know how I can use the template to add a generic label, but then add additional machine-specific labels when the VMs are created?

Here is the TF code:

```
// instance template
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "app" {
  name           = "appserver-template"
  machine_type   = var.app_machine_type
  labels = {
    costing = "app"
  }
  disk {
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.debian_image.self_link
    auto_delete  = true
    boot         = true
    disk_size_gb = 20
  }
  tags           = ["compute", "app"]
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  }
    // no access config
  service_account  {
    email  =  var.service_account_email
    // email  = google_service_account.vm_sa.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
}
// create instances --how to add instance-specific label here? eg component="admin"
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "admin" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = "admin-igm"

  base_instance_name = "${var.project_short_name}-admin"
  zone               = var.zone
  
  target_size = 1

  version {
    name              = "appserver"
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.app.id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired outcome by creating a google_compute_instance_template for each server type in my application, which then allowed me to assign both a universal label and a component-specific label.  It was more code than I hoped to have to write, but the objective is met.

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "admin" {
  name           = "admin-template"
  machine_type   = var.app_machine_type
  labels = {
    costing   = "app",
    component = "admin"
  }
  disk {
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.debian_image.self_link
    auto_delete  = true
    boot         = true
    disk_size_gb = 20
  }
  tags           = ["compute"]
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  }
    // no access config
  service_account  {
    email  =  var.service_account_email
    // email  = google_service_account.vm_sa.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
}
```